# Question regarding Alguno vs Algunos

Tags: gramática, pronombres, adjetivos

In an example given by Spanish Grammar Practice, it said:

> **Algunos** de mis amigos son estudiantes.

However, in a practice question which I tried to complete, I wrote

> ¿Quieres **algunos** de esos libros?

Instead, the correct answer is

> ¿Quieres **alguno** de esos libros?

This brings me to a few questions,

1. Is it possible that the question has multiple answers?
2. If my answer is wrong, why? ;(

From confused human being

Answer (score 3):

Your response, *¿Quieres algunos de esos libros?* is a perfectly valid question.  I can't say whether it would be a "correct" response, because I didn't see the whole exercise.

It's quite similar to English.  A librarian could ask a patron, "Would you like to check out one of these books?" or "Would you like to check out some of these books?"

Comment: ah I see, thanks for the proofread and response! It was just that a one-sentence fill in the blank question. The original: "¿Quieres ____ de esos libros?"

Comment: @SiriusTimeKeeper - Well, sometimes the person writing the exercise doesn't realize he's making an additional assumption.  I'm not familiar with your book, but I do know that sometimes in the textbook publishing industry the big name writes the chapters and provides an outline of what's needed in the exercise section, but some minions who may not even have read the chapter are the ones writing the exercises.

Comment: I don't know.. In questions I would always use the singular "Alguno" even if i'm referring to a "many".

Comment: @Mike - That's interesting.  Do you want to write an answer?  That could help us gauge if your tendency is universal.  Remember, I did not learn Spanish at my mother's knee.  As the librarian in the vignette, I'd be afraid the patron might think I was subtly letting them know they are only allowed to check out one book.  (On my last visit to Mexico, a lending library for children had recently opened.  They did allow only *one* book to be checked out at a time....)

Comment: i'm researching, but i haven't found sources other than usage ... i'll keep looking